# Links not working on Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, hyperlink, anchor

I'm trying to code a simple page jump. The red button on this page supposed to jump the page down to the next section. It seems to work EVERYWHERE but on the Safari browser, on mobile. Safari on Desktop is fine. I've tried a simple anchor tag, and java script to set the link and none are working. I've even tried linking to an external page to see if it was just the link to the ID, and the external link did not work either. At this point, I'm at a complete loss. Below is the CSS, Javascript, and HTML. I'm using Visual Composer inside of Wordpress to create the site, but it's almost all "Raw HTML" elements.

Here's the page: http://thirteenthfloor.com/presale/13thfloordenver/

..help

```html
<span 
  class="pseudolink" 
  onclick="location='http://thirteenthfloor.com/presale/13thfloordenver/#sales'">
<div class="buybutton">BUY TICKETS NOW</div>
</span>

<!--OR-->

<a href="#sales"><div class="buybutton">BUY TICKETS NOW</div></a>
```

```css
.buybutton {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(#be0000, #970000);
    width: 275px;
    padding: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 25px auto 0px auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #000;
}
.buybutton a{
    color: #fff;
}
.buybutton:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(#df0000, #cc0000);
    cursor: pointer;
    /**box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #000000;**/
}
```

Comment: have you seen any error in the console? did you try with this syntax: `onclick="window.location.hash='sales'"` too?

Comment: Just tried that syntax, and it's the same issue. Only not working on mobile for Safari. None of the page links work at all.

The console isn't registering any errors either.

Comment: Haven't got a solution, but the problem seems to be because the hash is lost between redirections/rewriting, as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643032/anchor-tag-doesnt-work-in-iphone-safari, unfortunately, your link syntax is already as they recommand

Comment: It's actually creating the "/#", as opposed to "#", just fine. Links of any kind arran't working, even to a completely different URL. Both anchor tags, and Javascript arran't working

Comment: Okay, so here's another odd detail. The links ARE REGISTERING, because if you press and HOLD the link on the iphone, then it will give you the option to open the link...

Comment: http://thirteenthfloor.com/page-test/ 

Same theme, no custom HTML, and no custom CSS, and it works

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately just a case of the iPhone software, Safari, and Visual Composer not wanting to work together. Best advise if this ever happens to you: don't use Visual Composer. "Salient" is a much better alternative for Wordpress.

Comment: never liked much Visual Composer anyway, page builders usually add too much complexity in the code imo, when they are not full of bugs.. I'll have a look at Salient anyway..