# Mobile: Anchor links/listeners only work on part of screen

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile-safari, shopify

I've got a website that works fine, but one page on the mobile view is acting up.

**Context**:

The page, and entire site, is using shopify liquid which is a html markup type language. This issue is only on one page of the site. All other pages work correctly.

I am performing this on an iPhone 6s using safari to access the website. I have the dev tools open via safari on my macbook. Only on a mobile device is this happening. User testing was also done using an iPhone 8 plus that was not hooked up to a computer, but behaved similarly.

A mobile rendering of the page via chrome dev tools does not produce any errors. Also, on my pixel 2 using mobile chrome there are no issues.

So from that I'm assuming its an safari/ios issue, and not a chrome/android issue.

**Behavior**:

There are anchor tags all throughout this page, but they only trigger if they are in the top probably 25-33% of the page. If the anchor text is positioned lower down on the page, nothing happens. There is also a footer that contains a bunch of anchor tags that only work if they can reach the upper portion of the page.

It has a header that contains 2 anchor tags and a right side hamburger menu(which should open up on click). Neither do anything regardless of the orientation of the page(given that the header stays at the top).

**QUESTION**:Is there some mobile ios behavior I'm missing?

I've done lots of testing by checking event handlers, making sure all the libraries are being loaded correctly, adding custom event listeners etc etc. but I haven't made any breakthroughs that would lead me to any action.

Comment: Have you read this?  Perhaps this might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643032/anchor-tag-doesnt-work-in-iphone-safari

Comment: Yeah, that question deals more with the anchor tag not going exactly where desired. My issue is the anchor tag not working or even being tappable. Or better said, their issue is anchor tag working wrong, mine is anchor tag(and listeners) not working at all.

Comment: Did you scroll down to the last answer that was downvoted?  It's possible his answer will provide you with the solution you're looking for.  It's likely he was downvoted for providing an answer that was not directly related to the question, but could possibly be the solution that will work for your scenario.  His answer suggested adding `target="_top` to the anchor tag.  It might be a shot in the dark but no harm in trying.