# Spring Redirect not working from iOS (fine from Desktop)

Tags: iphone, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, vue.js

I have a simple use case where the client wants to be able to redirect user-friendly urls to vue-router urls which are less so (with ids etc..). So I did the following (simplified example).

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class RedirectController {

    @Value("${server.baseUrl}")
    private String baseUrl;

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public RedirectController(final UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public String catchAll() {

        return "redirect:" + baseUrl;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{userName}")
    public String redirect(@PathVariable("userName") String userName) {

        String url = "/";

        if (userName.matches("[a-zA-Z]+(-[a-zA-Z]+)*")) {

            User user = userService.findByUserName(userName);

            if (user != null) {
                url += "#/users/" + user.getHashedId();
            }
        }
        return "redirect:" + baseUrl + url;
    }
}
```

So that works from desktop browsers but if I put https://www.example.com/users/some-user/ into Safari or Chrome on my iPhone. It redirects to "https://www.example.com/" despite (and I checked this with breakpoints etc.) the controller correctly returning "redirect:https://www.example.com/#/users/1623123465/".

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like this other SO-problem: [Safari looses anchor on redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643032/anchor-tag-doesnt-work-in-iphone-Safari).

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that. However it doesn't seem to be restricted to Safari. I just installed Chrome on my iPhone and I get the same problem...

Comment: Chrome on iOS is a wrapper around WebKit, the same browser engine that Safari uses.

Comment: I have the same issue....Have you been able to solve this problem?

Comment: @AlejoDev Ensuring that the baseUrl always uses https seems to work however I still have trouble with links in the Android Instagram app not working - although I think this may be an SSL certificate issue.