# Anchor to another page going to wrong element in mobile

Tags: html, caching, mobile, anchor

I have a dropdown menu where each option send the user to an element in another page. It is working perfectly for desktop, but in mobile it works fine only for the first time.

Example:  if in mobile the user select for example 
"Galway", the user will be sent to the page 2 and where galway element is, if after that the user go back to the main page and select "Dublin", the user will be sent to the page 2, but where the galway element is, instead of dublin. Even the url will be showing galway, and it will be always galway it doesn't matter what I try to select unless I clean the browser cache.

**In the page 1**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="/providers#provider-dublin">Dublin</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/providers#provider-galway">Galway</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/providers#provider-cork-city">Cork City</a>
    </li>
    <li>
</ul>
```

**In the page 2**

```
<div id="provider-dublin" class="same_width doctor_detail_wrap">
    <div class="doctor_img_wrap">
        <img src="https://clear.juvo.dev/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/cliona-fergey-circle-1-2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="doctor_detail">
        <h2>Blackrock</h2>
        <h3>Dr Cliona Fergey</h3>
        <h3>Dental Options Cork</h3>
        <p>Blackrock Hall Primary Care Centre</p>
        <p>Skehard Road</p>
        <p>Blackrock</p>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the other elements with different ids

Comment: were you able to replicate the issue is diffrent browser. Have you tried completing the url such as href="http://domain-name.com/providers#provider-cork-city"

Comment: I can replicate the issue even including the domain url in the link. I have only iphone so I tried in chrome and safari and the issue also happens in both.

Comment: Please check this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/22643441/3238940

Comment: @mightyteja Thank you so much... it fixed... I was getting crazy here.

Answer (score 0):

***The answer was copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22643441/3238940***

Opera, IE, Chrome and Firefox will carry over the anchor to the new page. However, Safari loses the anchor on the redirect.

So what if you add / just before the ID Tag?

*Old URL Path:*

> http://www.example.com/my-example-article-url-is-like.php#articlebottom

*New URL Path:*

> http://www.example.com/my-example-article-url-is-like.php/#articlebottom

Another solution is that you'd have to delete both "www." from the domain and add a forward slash before the anchor tag in the URL/pathname before Safari would respond properly. Firefox doesn't seem to care, and I haven't gotten to testing on IE yet.

```
***Hope this might help other's without much trouble.***
```