# <a> tag is not clickable in Safari, but it works fine in other browsers

Tags: html, css, angular, safari, cpanel

I have a problem, my header drop-down is not working in Safari; it works fine in Chrome browser, but the problem appears when I open Safari: I can't click my menu drop-down to open another drop-down. It is un-clickable, have you ever had this kind of problem? I am using `<a>` tags, and also tried `<span>`, but nothing changed.

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 0px 7%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 10000;
  .navbar ul {
    list-style: none;
  }
  .navbar ul li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
  }
  .navbar ul li a,
  span {
    padding: 20px;
    color: #111d5e !important;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar ul li a:after {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    box-shadow: inset 3000px 0 0 0 #eed484;
    transition: width 0.3s ease 0s, left 0.3s ease 0s;
    width: 0;
  }
  .navbar ul li a:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  .navbar ul li span:after {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    box-shadow: inset 3000px 0 0 0 #eed484;
    transition: width 0.3s ease 0s, left 0.3s ease 0s;
    width: 0;
  }
  .navbar ul li span:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  .navbar ul li ul li span,
  a {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 250px;
    background: #ffffff;
    display: none;
    align-items: flex
  }
  .navbar ul li ul li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  // .navbar ul li:focus-within > ul,
  .navbar ul li:hover>ul {
    display: initial;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  #menu-bar {
    display: none;
  }
  label {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #111d5e !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none
  }
  .navbar ul li .language {
    width: 155px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  header {
    padding: 15px;
  }
  header label {
    display: initial;
  }
  header .navbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 64px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
    display: none;
    z-index: 99999;
  }
  header .navbar ul li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  header .navbar ul li ul {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  header .navbar ul li ul li {
    background: #ffffff
  }
  header .navbar ul li ul li ul {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  #menu-bar:checked~.navbar {
    display: initial
  }
  header .navbar ul li .language {
    width: 100%;
  }
  header .navbar ul a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>

  <img routerLink="" style="cursor: pointer" src="assets/logo.png" alt="">


  <input type="checkbox" id="menu-bar">

  <label for="menu-bar">{{'header.fifth' | translate}}</label>


  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a routerLink="">{{'header.first' | translate}}</a></li>
      <li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>{{'header.second' | translate}} </a>
        <ul style="cursor: pointer;">
          <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" routerLink="/customs">{{'body.head-1' | translate}}</a></li>
          <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" routerLink="/terrestrial">{{'body.head-2' | translate}}</a></li>
          <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" routerLink="/ship">{{'body.head-3' | translate}}</a></li>
          <li><a style="cursor: pointer;" routerLink="/train">{{ 'body.head-4' | translate}}</a></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
      <li style="cursor: pointer;"><a>{{'header.fourth' | translate}}</a>
        <ul class="language" style="float: left !important; cursor: pointer;">
          <li><a (click)="setLang('ka')" style="cursor: pointer" class="dropdown-item">{{'language.first' | translate}}</a></li>
          <li><a (click)="setLang('en')" style="cursor: pointer" class="dropdown-item">{{'language.second' | translate}}</a> </li>
          <li><a (click)="setLang('ru')" style="cursor: pointer" class="dropdown-item">{{'language.third' | translate}}</a> </li>

        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anchor tag doesn't work in iPhone Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643032/anchor-tag-doesnt-work-in-iphone-safari)

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue rendering `<a>` tags as part of text that was unclickable.
Searching issues, I found something regarding `display:inline` not being supported.
When I added `display:inline-block` it fixed the issue.